# How to determine the size of the tension $T$ in the rope given the following information?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, string

A trolley of mass $1kg$ is being pulled along a rough horizontal table, the coefficient of friction between the two objects is $0.4$, with an acceleration of $3m/s^2$ to the right, by a rope at an angle of $tan^{-1}(\frac{3}{4})$ degrees to the horizontal, in a vertical plane.

Determine the size of the tension $T$ in the rope and the normal reaction $N$ of the table on the trolley. Give answer to 1 decimal place.

So first I drew a diagram representing all forces available. Like so:

[image]

I then tried to formulate the sum of all forces in horizontal and vertical direction.

F net x $= -$ F friction $+$ F tension x

F net y $= $ F normal $+$ F gravitational $+$ F tension

I also know that
[image]

This way I tried to form simultaneous equation, but I failed to get the correct answer. PS: The answers are $5.4N$; $130.8N$

Comment: It is simple equation solving. Homework based questions. Needs to be closed

Comment: @madhubalasingh I disagree. The questioner has put in effort and explained where they got stuck. It is not fair to close a question just because it is "simple" - we all have to start somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

I used force equations: (.8T - .4N = 3) and (.6T + N - 9.8 = 0) (assuming MKS units), and also disagree with the given answers.

Answer (score 0):

The two unknowns are the tension in the rope $T$, and the normal force $N$. The given angle $\tan^{-1} \frac 3 4$ means that $T$ can be resolved into components $0.8T$ horizontally and $0.6T$ vertically.

Vertically, the block is in equilibrium, so

$0.6T + N = mg \\ \Rightarrow 0.6T + N = 9.8$

Horizontally, there must be a net force of $3m$ to the right in order to accelerate the block at $3$ m/s^2. The frictional force, acting to the left, is $0.4N$, so

$0.8T - 0.4N = 3m \\ \Rightarrow 0.8T - 0.4N = 3$

Now you have two simultaneous equations which you can solve to find the values of $T$ and $N$. As pointed out in another answer, the actual solution does not match the values that you give in the question.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So there isn't a net force in the y direction? Can't I find the acceleration vertical direction too? Using $a = 3$ and $\theta$ and therefore$3tan36.9 =$ acceleration y

Comment: Would the vertical equation becomes $2.3 = N - 9.8+ 0.6T$ instead of $0 = N - 9.8 + 0.6T$.Sorry but how do you know the block is in equilibrium?

Comment: @Nhoj_Gonk Where does the figure $2.3$ come from. It does not seem to be related to any of the data in the problem. The block is in *vertical* equilibrium because it is not accelerating vertically, only horizontally.